# PHP copy file permissions denied with dynamic user system

Tags: php

I am trying to copy a file to user's directory. I run a small hosting service with every user having a seperate directory. I can't CHMOD the directories to allow the PHP (www-data) user as that will break FTP for the users and some other programs we have installed on our server.

However, PHP (the www-data) user, is allowed to run with sudo. is this a possible fix? If it is: how to run copy() with sudo.

If that is not possible, is there another solution for my problem?

Exact error:

> PHP Warning:  copy(/home/user_946221/383838/Modules/xxx.zip): failed
>   to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /panel/handlers/server_functions/download.php

Thanks,
Jesse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do `exec("sudo cp from to")`

Best regards